# Hide ToolBar in Landscape mode Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a MasterPage and i want to hide **ToolBar** in Landscape Mode, but to be able to interact with **MasterDetailPage**. I saw this in Google Calendar:[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement device orientation logic (use plugin, for example: https://github.com/aliozgur/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/DeviceOrientation or implement by yourself with dependency service), then:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    _RotatePage();

    SizeChanged += _SizeChanged;
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    SizeChanged -= _SizeChanged;

    base.OnDisappearing();
}

private void _SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var svc = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceOrientationService>();
    var orientation = svc.GetOrientation();

    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, orientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait);
}
```